# How to set a log filename to the name of the invoked Java class?

Tags: java, config, logback

I have the following simple `FileAppender` in Logback.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>my_logger.log</file>
    <append>false</append>

    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%date{dd MMM HH:mm}|%class{0}|%-5level|%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

How can I modify it so that the filename is not `my_logger.log`, but is dynamically set to the name of the invoked Java class?
Can I achieve this by modifying Logback's config file, or do I need to write some piece of code?

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think you achieve that by **not** specifying <file> tag

Comment: No, you get an error: `ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - "File" property not set for appender named [FILE].`